# Cant import JS library to my Nuxt project

Tags: vue.js, plugins, import, module, nuxt.js

I have weird problem.
I want use this hover-effect library (https://github.com/robin-dela/hover-effect) in my nuxt project.
This i have in my contact.vue in script tags

```
import hoverEffect from 'hover-effect'

export default {
    mounted() {
        const effect = new hoverEffect({
            parent: document.querySelector('.right-section'),
            intensity: 0.3,
            image1: require('@/assets/images/1.jpg'),
            image2: require('@/assets/images/2.jpg'),
            displacementImage: require('@/assets/images/dist2.jpg'),
        })
    },
}
```

And that effect works perfectly.. BUT when i refresh the page i got this error:
**SyntaxError Cannot use import statement outside a module**

So i tried add this plugin into **plugins/hover-effect.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import hoverEffect from 'hover-effect'

Vue.use(hoverEffect)
```

then in **nuxt.config.js**

```
plugins: [{ src: '~/plugins/hover-effect', mode: 'client' }],
```

But nothing works.. its always error: **hoverEffect is not defined**. I tried another 20 ways with no success. I tried this effect in normal Vue project and it works but not in nuxt.js. Can somebody help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

You can configure it in the `head` of the page:

Page.vue

```js
export default {
  head() {
    return {
      script: [
        {src: '../dist/hover-effect.umd.js'}
      ]
    }
  },
...

mounted() {
        const effect = new hoverEffect({
            parent: document.querySelector('.right-section'),
            intensity: 0.3,
            image1: require('@/assets/images/1.jpg'),
            image2: require('@/assets/images/2.jpg'),
            displacementImage: require('@/assets/images/dist2.jpg'),
        })
    },
```

Comment: it doesnt work, Cannot read property 'Scene' of undefined
    at new <anonymous> (hover-effect.umd.js:1) i dont get it.. but thank you

Answer (score 0):

```js
modules: [
    // Doc: https://axios.nuxtjs.org/usage
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    // Doc: https://github.com/nuxt/content
    '@nuxt/content',
    'hover-effect'
],
```

Have you tried to add hover-effect library to modules in nuxt.config.js file? All I did was install the package and add it to the module and then have the same code as your script tag. Hope it helped you!